# Open Ports - Strange Errors

Tags: networking, isp, ports

I was doing an open port check 1-65535 on my external IP from an online tool and I could see 5 open ports! When I opened one of them in my browser `myip:3541` and I could see only this response:

> Bearclaw. Cornstalk. Turtles. Get Yolked. 4181.

Another response on another port was this:

```
ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
```

The other ports just show blank. When I checked for my pc open ports they weren't in my "netstat -aon". After some minutes I checked again for open ports and now those open ports were different. Could it be my fault or my ISP's fault and if anyone knows what does that mean? I have dynamic IP and the same thing happened with 2 different IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are ports currently being used, most likely by your browser.

The first message is associated with [AdMob ads](http://http-sniffer.find-my-search.com/en/web-sniff-of/ads.mopub.com/), and the second is a session with CloudFront, [Amazon's CDN](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).

When you browse to a page, your browser downloads the requested URL, and parses the document. in the pages markup, there are usually references to many other sites, including remote content, analytics engines, javascripts, stylesheets, ad networks, etc. 
for each one of these items, the browser performs a GET request, and adds the content to the page as it is rendered.

it looks like you are accessing the ports used in some of these 'sub-page' connections, and are seeing the HTML text resulting from that connection.